# NSUserDefaults values becoming nil

Tags: iphone, ios7, nsuserdefaults

I am observing strange behaviour of NSUserDefaults. During testing on iphone 4(32-bit) it is working fine. When i send the same app to my client using iPhone 5S(64-bit), NSUserDefault values are becoming nil. Is the behaviour of NSUserDefaults is changing on **32-bit** and **64-bit** ios versions? I have also used **[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize]** after saving values in NSUserDefaults.I am observing this kind of behaviour from ios 7.1 versions.

**AppDelegate.m**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
   //to stop updating locations in subsequent launches
if (![@"1" isEqualToString:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                                objectForKey:@"aValue"]]) {

        //Action here
        NSLog(@"LOCATION IS ON");
        locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        locationVC  = [[LocationVC alloc]init];
        [locationVC InitializeWith:_managedObjectContext LocationManager:locationManager];
        //[locationVC InitializeWith:_managedObjectContext LocationManager:nil];

    }

    else {

        NSLog(@"LOCATION IS OFF");
        locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        locationVC  = [[LocationVC alloc]init];
        //[locationVC InitializeWith:_managedObjectContext LocationManager:locationManager];
        [locationVC InitializeWith:_managedObjectContext LocationManager:nil];

    }
}
```

**LocationVC.m**

```
    LocationVC *locationVC;

-(void) InitializeWith:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context LocationManager:(CLLocationManager *)locationManager{

    //to update location during first launch
    if (![@"1" isEqualToString:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                                objectForKey:@"aValue"]]) {

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@"1" forKey:@"aValue"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        NSLog(@"LOCATION IS ON");
       self->locationManager=locationManager;
       self->locationManager.delegate = self;
       self->locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
       self->locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
       [self->locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

        _managedObjectContext=context;      
    }
    //in subsequent launches 
    else{       
        NSLog(@"LOCATION IS OFF");
         _managedObjectContext=context;
         [self->locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    }
}
```

In my client's iPhone 5S(64-bit), location icon is reappearing after 10 minutes eventhough i have called **[self->locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];** in subsequent application lauches.

Comment: Can you show an example of where you are writing, and getting back, the values from defaults? There clearly isn't a new behaviour in defaults that randomly removes any value, I think it would have been a bigger deal by now.

Comment: There's probably an error in your code where you're not using appropriate variable types to work on both 32- and 64- bit systems. But nobody can tell you without seeing the code.

Comment: add your userdefault code for check what's problem in your code.

Comment: Does your app ever get launched in the background by a location change (or push notification)? If you have 'encryption at rest' enabled your app could be launched in the background (presumably while the phone is locked) and the NSUserDefaults are inaccessible.

You can query this via [[UIApplication sharedApplication] isProtectedDataAvailable]

if that returns NO you would not have access to protected data(or keychain)

Answer (score 0):

> Is the behaviour of NSUserDefaults is changing on 32-bit and 64-bit ios versions?

No, `NSUserDefaults` (based on property lists) are designed to be platform independent. You can even copy a binary plist file from a Power PC Mac to an Intel machine, an iPhone 32 bit, or iPhone 64 bit and the file will always produce identical results.

The `NSUserDefaults` class is known to be very robust.

It's very likely that the error is in your code. If you need more help, please provide more information about how you detect and reproduce the error.

Edit: It seems that you used the wrong method to set @"aValue":

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@"1" forKey:@"aValue"];
```

The correct method to set preferences is `-setObject:forKey:`.

`setValue:fortKey:` is part of KVC and is not documented to do something specific in `NSUserDefaults`. While it seems that in current implementations (iOS 7.1) `NSUserDefaults` overrides `setValue:forKey:` that's an undocumented feature not guaranteed to work as expected.